# Error while opening apk created using kivy

Tags: python, android, kivy, kivymd, mediapipe

I'm trying to use `mediapipe`, but everytime this error occurs:

> ImportError: dlopen failed: "data/data/org.test.myapp/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/mediapipe/python/_framework_bindings.so" has unexpected e_machine: 62 (EM_X86_64)

I've created other apps, they work fine. But while using `mediapipe`, it is causing error.

Device: Nokia 6
Android version : 9

### Code:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.screen import Screen
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFlatButton
from kivy.graphics.texture import Texture
from kivy import platform
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp

if platform == "android":
    from android.permissions import Permission, request_permissions

    request_permissions([Permission.CAMERA])

mp_hands = mp.solutions.hands
mp_drawing = mp.solutions.drawing_utils


class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Orange"
        screen = Screen()
        self.label = MDLabel(text="Initializing...", halign="left", pos_hint={"center_y": 0.95},
                             theme_text_color="Custom", text_color=(0, 1, 0, 1),
                             font_style="Subtitle1")

        screen.add_widget(self.label)
        self.img1 = Image()
        screen.add_widget(self.img1)
        self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1.0 / 30.0)
        return screen

    def update(self, dt):
        cap = self.capture
        with mp_hands.Hands(model_complexity=0, min_detection_confidence=0.5, min_tracking_confidence=0.5) as hand:
            succ, frame = cap.read()
            if (not succ):
                close_btn = MDFlatButton(text="Close", on_release=self.close_dialog)
                self.dialog = MDDialog(title="User Detail", text="Something went wrong", size_hint=(0.7, 1),
                                       buttons=[close_btn])
                self.dialog.open()
                return

            img, res = self.mediapipe_detection(frame, hand)

            if (res.multi_hand_landmarks):
                for landmarks in res.multi_hand_landmarks:
                    for co in landmarks.landmark:
                        self.label.text = str(co.x) + "_" + str(co.y) + "_" + str(co.z)

            self.draw_landmarks(img, res)

            img = cv2.flip(img, 0)
            buf = img.tostring()
            texture1 = Texture.create(size=(img.shape[1], img.shape[0]), colorfmt="bgr")
            texture1.blit_buffer(buf, colorfmt="bgr", bufferfmt="ubyte")
            self.img1.texture = texture1

    def close_dialog(self, obj):
        self.dialog.dismiss()

    def mediapipe_detection(self, img, model):
        img = cv2.flip(img, 1)  # flip around y axis
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)  # converts image from BGR to RGB
        img.flags.writeable = False
        res = model.process(img)  # predicts
        img.flags.writeable = True
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)  # converts image from RGB to BGR
        return img, res

    def draw_landmarks(self, img, res):
        # draw hand landmarks
        if (res.multi_hand_landmarks):
            for landmarks in res.multi_hand_landmarks:
                mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(img, landmarks, mp_hands.HAND_CONNECTIONS)


MainApp().run()
```

---

Buildozer.spec
Requirements: python3,kivy,kivymd,mediapipe,numpy,opencv

Permission: INTERNET,CAMERA

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I've provided code along with buildozer.spec requirements and permission. Kindly help me please.

Answer (score 0):

I see you have pillow missing in your requirements, add pillow and try.